# Issue in passing a structure to a function accepting void * parameter

Tags: c, pointers, struct, parameter-passing, void

I want to call a function of type `foo(void * data)` having as input parameter a struct variable.

I have heard that when the input format is of type void, it accepts every type of input variable type. Nevertheless, I get an error message.

```
struct info{
    int element;
};

struct info inserter_info;
inserter_info.element = 0;

inserter(inserter_info);
```

Where `inserter()` is prototyped as `void * inserter(void * data)`.

I  tried casting but then also I got error messages.

Comment: *What* error messages do you get? When posting questions regarding errors, always include the actual errors (complete and unedited) in the question. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: You can find some relevant information here http://stackoverflow.com/q/23805910/2436175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I have heard that when the input format is of type void, it accepts every type of input variable type*

Absolutely wrong !!! `void` means *nothing*. It *accepts* nothing.

However, `void *` is *considered* a generic pointer. To quote the `C11` standard document, chapter 6.3.2.3, pointers, paragaraph 1,

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

using this attribute, many a times, the function parameter is written as `void *` so that, the function can accept different types of pointer and then, inside function body, based on some other paramater, that received pointer is converted (casted) back to the actual pointer type before using it.

If you check properly, the parameter to the function is not `void`, it's `void *`.

You need to call your function like

```
inserter(&inserter_info);
```

P.S - Your compiler should have warned you regarding the mismatch.

Comment: and how could I afterwards get the value of element? I have tried with int a = (int) data.element; inside the inserter method but it raises compilation errors

Comment: @user1920212 nopes, not like that. take `struct info * if = data; int a = if->element;`. Hope this clears up the issue. Frankly, if you're not much familiar with pointers, I suggest to go through the basics first.

Answer (score 1):

`void *data` is expecting a pointer

Here:

```
struct info inserter_info;
inserter_info.element = 0;
inserter(inserter_info);
```

you are not passing a pointer, change to:

```
inserter(&inserter_info);
```

Answer (score 1):

It expects a pointer, but you are not passing a pointer, if the `inserter()` function is going to run in a different thread you need to allocate the struct on the heap, otherwise it will be deallocated when the thread starts.

```
struct info {
    int element;
};

struct info *inserter_info;
inserter_info = malloc(sizeof(*inserter_info));
if (inserter_info == NULL)
    abortThisOperation();
inserter_info->element = 0;

inserter(inserter_info);
```

you should ensure that when the thread has finished working you will free the allocated pointer.

If the function is not going to run from a different thread then passing the address of the struct like this

```
struct info inserter_info;
inserter_info.element = 0;

inserter(&inserter_info);
```

would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

> I have heard that when the input format is of type void, it accepts every type of input variable type

A *pointer* to void accepts any other pointer to *object type*. Conversions between `void*` and a pointer to *function type* is undefined behavior, it is not covered by the standard.

Still the standard lists this as a "common language extension", meaning that such casts may be ok on your given system, but only if your compiler has implemented a non-standard extension.

In practice, pointers almost always corresponds directly to raw CPU addresses, in which case there is most often no difference between an address of a variable and the address of a function. So in the real world outside the C standard, you will probably get away with such casts.

Otherwise you can "hack the C standard" by first converting your function pointer into an integer type (such as uintptr_t) and then convert it to a `void*` from there. In that case the code only invokes undefined behavior in case the pointer cannot be represented as an integer (which is very unlikely).